# Looking for a simple pixel drawing method in ios (iphone, ipad)

Tags: ios, drawing, pixel

I have a simple drawing issue.  I have prepared a 2 dimensional array which has an animated wave motion.  The array is updated every 1/10th of a second (this can be changed by the user). After the array is updated I want to display it as a 2 dimensional image with each array value as a pixel with color range from 0 to 255.

Any pointers on how to do this most efficiently...

Appreciate any help on this...

KAS

Comment: How do the values 0 to 255 map to colours? Is it a straight greyscale-type affair, or do you have a spectrum of hues?

Comment: Tommy.. This would be a simple grey shade image, hopefully showing a traveling sine wave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a greyscale then the following (coded as I type, probably worth checking for errors) should work:

```
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider =
       CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, pointerToYourData, width*height, NULL);

CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGImageRef inputImage = CGImageCreate(  width, height,
                                        8, 8, width, 
                                        colourSpace, 
                                        kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                        dataProvider,
                                        NULL, NO,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:inputImage];
CGImageRelease(inputImage);

someImageView.image = image;
```

That'd be for a one-shot display, assuming you didn't want to write a custom UIView subclass (which is worth the effort only if performance is a problem, probably).

My understanding from the docs is that the data provider can be created just once for the lifetime of your C buffer. I don't think that's true of the image, but if you created a CGBitmapContext to wrap your buffer rather than a provider and an image, that would safely persist and you could use `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` to get a CGImageRef to be moving on with. It's probably worth benchmarking both ways around if it's an issue.

EDIT: so the alternative way around would be:

```
// get a context from your C buffer; this is now something
// CoreGraphics could draw to...
CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGContextRef context = 
        CGBitmapContextCreate(pointerToYourData,
                              width, height,
                              8, width,
                              colourSpace,
                              kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

// get an image of the context, which is something
// CoreGraphics can draw from...
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

/* wrap in a UIImage, push to a UIImageView, as before, remember
   to clean up 'image' */
```

CoreGraphics copies things about very lazily, so neither of these solutions should be as costly as the multiple steps imply.

Comment: You da man Tommy.. both solutions work.  I am going with the first solution and the performance is decent enough at the moment so I am not worried about subclassing the UIView yet... Thanks.

Comment: Tommy... How do you clear the animation sequence in UIImageView.  The above code suggestions solved my animation requirements.  I have loaded the frames in an NSMutableArray and added them to the UImageView.  That part works really well. Now I want to the stop the animations ( which is a simple (imageView.stopanimaiton ), however when I load a new array of images, I still get the old images as part of the new sequence.  I have tried removing all objects in the mutable array and re-initializing the array but can't seem to get rid of the old images.

Comment: OK..never mind :-)
The problem had nothing to do with the UIViewImage arrays.. I had defined some global variables which I had forgotten to reset. Another reminder to me about minimizing the usage of globals...